# If we know the exact value of the population parameter , is there any point in doing the hypothesis testing?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, sampling, inference, descriptive-statistics

Question - In a year there are 956 births in a town A of which 52.5% were males, while in town A and B combined, this proportion in a total of 1406 births was 0.496. Is there any significant difference in the proportion of male births in the two towns?

Isn't the Question mentioned above (same question with its solution is attached as image for reference) is wrong ?

The question is asking if there is any significant difference in proportion of male births, but my point is that if you know the exact proportion of male births in the two towns then you already know the **exact** difference between them. Then what's the point of finding if the difference is significant or not ?

In other words, if you know the exact difference of male births and exact number of total births then what's the point of hypothesis testing ?

[image]

Comment: Hi mkt, my doubt is - If you know the exact proportion of male births in the two towns then you already know the exact difference between them. Then is it relevant to find out if the difference is significant or not ?

Comment: You are using a screenshot of a question as motivation. This makes it hard for  users with vision impairments to participate. Please type that part out.

Comment: Hi, thanks for pointing out. Have typed the question.

Comment: You don't know the population parameters; all you have is their estimates based on a sample.